# Is IComparable the best way to use to enforce unique keys in Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, primary-key, icomparable

I have a class MyClass, and I want to put it as the key to a Dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary<MyClass, string> dict = new Dictionary<MyClass, string>();
```

I want to ensure that MyClass is a unique key, and uniqueness is specified by looking at `MyClass.UniqueProperty`. My first thought was to overload the `==` operator, but I found that C# does not allow this. Then I found the IComparable interface. Will this do the trick? Or should I overload Object.Equals(obj)?

Comment: FYI, C# **does** allow overloading the == operator, but it is bound by some rules and `Dictionary` doesn't use it.

Comment: Operators aren't virtual in C#, that's the only problem. You can override them, but the version that's called is determined at compile-time. Unless you're using `dynamic`, of course :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionary is well prepared for customized equality rules. That's why it has a constructor that takes `IEqualityComparer` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072(v=vs.110).aspx).

Since you only care about equality in the context of the dictionary, `IEqualityComparer<MyClass>` is the most straight-forward solution.

Primitive example:

```
void Main()
{
  var dict = new Dictionary<MyClass, string>(new MyClassUniqueIdEqualityComparer());

  dict.Add(new UserQuery.MyClass { UniqueId = 1 }, "Hi!");

  dict.ContainsKey(new UserQuery.MyClass { UniqueId = 2 }).Dump(); // False
  dict.ContainsKey(new UserQuery.MyClass { UniqueId = 1 }).Dump(); // True
}

public class MyClass
{
  public int UniqueId { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassUniqueIdEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
  public bool Equals(MyClass a, MyClass b) 
  {
    return a.UniqueId == b.UniqueId;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(MyClass a)
  {
    return a.UniqueId.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

The main benefit is that the equality rules only apply as defined by the equality comparer. You don't have to ensure proper equality between e.g. a derived class and a base class - it's all just within the contract of the dictionary and the comparer. Since the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods aren't virtual with respect to the dictionary, they allow equality even between different types, as long as they implement the same interface - something you really don't want to do with `object.Equals`, `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: This is a good approach if you don't want to modify the class you've created to support this equality check. You may want to make the class "equal" when `UniqueProperty` matches on two instances for the purpose of this specific dictionary, but not in every single other scenario where that class is used. This enables you to keep the equality comparison separate from the class. If you *always* wanted instances with the same `UniqueProperty` to be equal then you would override `Equals` on the object itself.

Comment: @ScottHannen Yeah, and overriding `Equals` has actually quite strict rules. For one, `Equals(a, b)` must be the same as `Equals(b, a)`, which is quite tricky since `Equals` is virtual, so if `b` is derived from `a`, you're in trouble. Most implementations just throw an error if the two types aren't exactly the same. Depending on the use, it can also lead to loss of data, e.g. the common `TryAdd` scenario. `IEqualityComparer` is a lot more explicit - you're not pretending two objects are equal just because they have the same ID, you always know you're only comparing the IDs.

Answer (score 3):

> Is `IComparable` the best way to use to enforce unique keys in Dictionary?

No - `IComparable` is for seeing if one object is greater than, equal to, or less than another.  It is primarily used in sorting routines.  It *can* be used to see if two objects are equal, but it is not the "best" way.

> Or should I overload `Object.Equals(obj)`?

Yes.  You can also implement `IEquatable<T>`, which is usually trivial if you've already overridden `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) appropriately.

Note that the implementaion of `GetHashCode` is critical if you're using the object as a hash key.  There are [many guidelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode) to follow to implement  proper hashing routine, and it's trickier that just comparing equality.

> My first thought was to overload the `==` operator, but I found that C# does not allow this.

Well, you can, but it's not appropriate for what you're doing.  The `==` operator is conventionally used for *reference* equality, meaning *"do these two variables point to the same instance"*.  `Object.Equals` is more appropriate for *value* equality, meaning *"are these two objects really describing the same thing"*